# Host WordPress on path on Cloudflare

Tags: wordpress, dns, web-hosting, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

My domain is managed by Cloudflare, and I want `example.com/he/whatevs` to point to an IP where WP is hosted, eg 11.2222.12.12/whatevs

For that I have `example.com` pointing to a worker script that redirects /he to the aforementioned IP.

For this to work on WP end, I changed to DB record of the root URL to `example.com/he`, since this is the "user facing" URL.

The problem is, when I try to login to WP, there's a redirect mechanism in there that seems to be built-in to WP, and that causes an infinite redirect loop that eventually errors out.

Any ideas how to walk around that?

Or maybe my entire approach is off?

Comment: How have you defined the WP_HOME and WP_SITEURL variables?  https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/

Comment: What is the worker for, then. Wouldn't it be faster to navigate directly to `example.com/he`? Or did you mean to make that url sort of private?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with cloudflare's default SSL setting, which is "flexible".

Once I changed it to "full strict" it started working.